# Как запустить тест через консоль

Tags: c#, visual-studio, юнит-тесты, test-automation

Создал на шарпах Unit Test Project в MS Visual Studio. Успешно запускаю через test->run-> all test, однако возник вопрос-как их запустить через консоль? Поскольку появилось желание их гонять через что-нибудь типа jenkins

Comment: Можно конкретнее, что имеется ввиду под "что-нибудь типа Jenkins"? Например, есть TeamCity, в нём имеется специальный runner для запуска тестов (пример статьи про [настройку](https://habr.com/en/company/skbkontur/blog/205402/)), в Jenkins вероятно свой имеется. Поэтому если вам нужен какой-то конкретный CI - укажите его. В студии же локально тесты запускают не через консоль, а прямо из студии - один тест, пачку тестов... В общем, вопрос требует уточнения.

Comment: не знаю, что такое jenkins, но гуглится вот это [MSTest Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSTest+Plugin), [MSTestRunner Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSTestRunner+Plugin)

Comment: Вообще компания рассматривает варианты прогона тестов либо в TFS(наиболее вероятно), либо в Jenkins, т.к. сам таким не занимался, а только изучаю вопрос, то мб не смогу дать более развёрнутый ответ

Comment: @AK TFS это не только CVS, это, по сути, уже [решение всё в одном](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/overview?view=azure-devops-2019)

Comment: Тесты в консоли запускаются через MSTest.exe или VSTest.exe. Про MSTest есть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12304651/5796587)

Comment: Тесты можно запустить через MSTest / VSTest для классического .NET, через dotnet test для .net core.